# hide image inside UItableview cell when button is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a cell that contains labels and image. When user clicks on the edit button on top of the View Controller I want the image inside the cell to appear and when the edit button is clicked again the image should be hidden.

The closest example is the email cells in the iPhone. when I click on the edit button every email has a checkbox next to it and when I click cancel the check disappears.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide some code or things you have already tried.

Comment: You could use the `.isHidden` property, that every `UIView` subclass has. Just set it to `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some easy way to start with is to create some property `isImageDisplaying` which will indicate current state of your view controller. When user click to the button you will simply change the state of this var and reload your table view. Here you can find some sample solution:

```
var isImageDisplaying: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

@IBAction func editButtonDidClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    isImageDisplaying = !isImageDisplaying
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ... // get cell
    cell.imageView.isHidden = !isImageDisplaying
    // configure rest of the cell
    return cell
}
```